# my defined python class method does not work

Tags: python-3.x, class

```
class QuizBrain:
    def __init__(self,question_list):
        self.question_list = question_list
        self.question_number = 0
        self.score = 0

    def still_has_questions(self):
        if len(self.question_list) == self.question_number:
            return False
        return True

    

    def check_the_answer(self,user,answer):
        if user.lower() == answer.lower():
            self.score += 1
            print("Correct answer ...")
        else:
            print("Thats wrong")
        print(f"Score: {self.score}/{self.question_number}")
        print("n/")
        


    def next_question(self):
        question = self.question_list[self.question_number].text
        answer = self.question_list[self.question_number].answer
        self.question_number += 1
        
        user = input(f"Q.{self.question_number}: {question} (True/False) --> ")
        check_the_answer(user,answer)
```

NameError: name 'check_the_answer' is not defined

I get this error when ı try the run the program ıdk why ı defined that
I just started to learn if you can explain with details it would be nice

Comment: Must be `self.check_the_answer`.

Comment: The error's pretty clear? You're calling `check_the_answer(user, answer)`, which doesn't exist. So we look at the code, and see that the class has that function, but we also know that we need to call instance functions using `self`, which your code isn't doing. It's trying to call some global function called `check_the_answer`) instead. So that should be easy enough to fix.